# What are some cases that involve moral themes?

Tags: kant, aristotle, john-stuart-mill

I am searching for a specific case that interests me, where I can discuss Kantian ethics, Utilitarianism (Mill and Bentham), and Aristotle's Virtue Ethics. So far, the cases I have come across on the web do not spark interest in me and was curious to what cases may involve these moral themes. I am seeking inspiration, so please feel free to mention anything from links to where I can find such cases.

I am essentially looking for some ideas/cases that will allow me to look at the situation from the perspectives of all: Aristotle, Kant, and Mill). A great answer would just be the mention of a specific or list of cases you feel can be talked about in regards to all three of these philosophies. Thank you!

Comment: What exactly are you looking for with a "case"? Can you unpack this a little further? (What does a great answer to this question look like in your mind?)

Comment: @JosephWeissman perhaps the mention of a specific crime case that has caught your attention in the past, or a mystery case (i.e. the Kitty Genovese case and how Kant would suggest telling the murderer the truth if he were to ask where the victim was hiding). I am essentially looking for some ideas/cases that will allow me to look at the situation from the perspectives of all: Aristotle, Kant, and Mill). A great answer would just be the mention of a specific or list of cases you feel can be talked about in regards to all three of these philosophies.

Comment: Thing is: You are essentially asking for something you deem suitable. There is nothing that makes an answer "correct". StackExchange is also not about what people feel. What you may ask for are cases that already had been discussed in all three frameworks (e.g. Sophie's Choice).

Comment: @PhilipKlöcking I see, it would essentially be a personal-choice type of question that I am asking. Thank you. Although, I am curious to which cases have been discussed in all three frameworks and hopefully that will help me choose one.

Comment: Could you at least specify which "moral themes" attract you, and give examples of "cases" with brief explanations of what they are lacking for you.

Comment: You could discuss *To Kill a Mockingbird* and *Huckleberry Finn*, both of which treats racism in the deep south. Theres also Thomas Mann *The Magic Mountain* which apparently about fin-de-seicle Europe, but I was never able to get into that novel.

Answer (score 1):

Moral dilemmas are always a good source of fiction or exercise of the moral imagination.

You might get some ideas by adopting and adapting any of these storylines :

https://www.buzzfeed.com/tracyclayton/moral-dilemmas-that-will-break-your-brain?utm_term=.lcxKxlGAz#.noQkxlK39

http://listverse.com/2007/10/21/top-10-moral-dilemmas/

http://psychopixi.com/uncategorized/25-moral-dilemmas/

http://www.friesian.com/valley/dilemmas.htm

https://thoughtcatalog.com/lenna-son/2014/06/3-famous-moral-dilemmas-that-will-really-make-you-think/

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/23010)

Comment: @Dan Hicks. Point taken. Answer revised.

Answer (score 0):

One suggestion is the study of actual criminal cases that are well documented by the Justice departments all over the world. You could maybe apply your ideas and thoughts in relation to the verdicts that were passed.

Comment: This was a famous civil case:  https://www.casebriefs.com/blog/law/contracts/contracts-keyed-to-murphy/avoidance-of-contracts/vokes-v-arthur-murray-inc-2/  This case brief does not do it justice. The full opinion may be online somewhere. Note on the link: there are two pages to read.  I think that for Kant, the trade puffing in itself, and in any circumstance,  would be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

While not a criminal case, you do allow for "ideas."

The Trolley Dilemma is a classic in the realm of ethics. If not familiar with it; the general idea is there is a trolley on path to strike and kill 5 people. You have the ability flip a switch in order to switch tracks before the catastrophe, although on that track is one person who would consequently be struck and killed. The choice and the reasoning behind it can be attributed to several different notions of ethics and morality.

This website gives an overview, options you have, and the corresponding view of morality associated with said options.

http://www.trolleydilemma.com/

Answer (score 0):

The [Heinz Dilemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heinz_dilemma) is mainly used to contrast deontology and consequentialism. You should be able to throw virtue ethics in there as well. But imo then the result could go either way depending on the particular virtue ethics. Whereas with deontology and consequentialism (in general) it's a little more clear-cut.

Apart from that animal ethics is quite suited to discuss the argumentations of the various approaches of normative ethics.

Answer (score 0):

You might like to reconsider some of the contemporary cases here, from various perspectives http://blog.practicalethics.ox.ac.uk

Singer in his book *Practical Ethics* considers topics of: race, sex, ability, species, abortion, euthanasia, infanticide, embryo experimentation, the moral status of animals, political violence, overseas aid, whether we have an obligation to assist others, refugees, the environment, equality and disability, embryo experimentation, the treatment of academics in Germany, and climate change. And gives you the utilitarian perspective to get started.